# Creating method which must be included in other forms

Tags: winforms, inheritance

Apologies in advance for the amateur nature of this question.

I am developing a Windows Forms Application and I am wondering how can I implement a method in a Baseform which then has to be implemented in all forms which inherit from this?

For example I have this as my baseform:

```
public partial class Baseform : RadForm
{
    public Baseform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

How do I then add a method to this class, so that every form that I create like this:

```
public partial class CustomForm : Baseform
{
    public CustomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

has to declare this method?

Any help / direction to other resources is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Forms are just classes, and you use the C# inheritance rules to play with it. So if you want state the children implement a function declare the base abstract with one ( or possibly more ) [abstract methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).